# Why have both itraverse and itraversed functions in Haskell's lens library?

Tags: haskell, indexing, traversal, haskell-lens

The Haskell library [lens](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens) contains a type class [TraversableWithIndex](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-4.15.2/docs/Control-Lens-Indexed.html#t:TraversableWithIndex) that defines both the functions [itraverse](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-4.15.2/docs/Control-Lens-Indexed.html#v:itraverse) and [itraversed](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-4.15.2/docs/Control-Lens-Indexed.html#v:itraversed):

```
class
    (FunctorWithIndex i t, FoldableWithIndex i t, Traversable t)
    => TraversableWithIndex i t | t -> i where
  itraverse :: Applicative f => (i -> a -> f b) -> t a -> f (t b)
  itraversed :: IndexedTraversal i (t a) (t b) a b
```

`IndexedTraversal` expands like this:

```
type IndexedTraversal i s t a b =
  forall p f. (Indexable i p, Applicative f) => p a (f b) -> s -> f t
```

`itraverse` and `itraversed` seem very similar.  *Why are both needed?*

---

From playing around with `itraverse` and `itraversed`, it appears that `itraversed` is the only one of the two that can be used with [`%@~`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-4.15.2/docs/Control-Lens-Setter.html#v:-37--64--126-) as an [`AnIndexedSetter`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-4.15.2/docs/Control-Lens-Setter.html#t:AnIndexedSetter).

Here are the types of `%@~`, `AnIndexedSetter`, and `Indexed` for completeness:

```
(%@~) :: AnIndexedSetter i s t a b -> (i -> a -> b) -> s -> t 

type AnIndexedSetter i s t a b =
  Indexed i a (Identity b) -> s -> Identity t 

newtype Indexed i a b = Indexed { runIndexed :: i -> a -> b }
```

Why does `%@~` require `AnIndexedSetter`?  Why does `Indexed` have to be used anyway?

Using `Indexed` seems like it would make composition more difficult, since it is not a normal function.  *What am I missing here?*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Indexed optics aren't as simple as regular ones. Regular `Traversal` is simple:

```
type Traversal s t a b = forall f. Applicative f => (a -> f b) -> s -> f t
```

That is exactly the type of `traverse` with `s = c a` and `t = c b`, where `c` is a `Traversable`.

You could imagine that `IndexedTraversal i` is something similar with `(i -> a -> f b)`; but it isn't!

```
type IndexedTraversal i s t a b =
    forall p f. (Indexable i p, Applicative f) => p a (f b) -> s -> f t
```

The `Indexable i p` constraint is satisfied by `(->)` and `Indexed`, so:

```
itraverse  :: Applicative f => (i -> a -> f b) -> s -> f t
itraversed :: Applicative f =>      (a -> f b) -> s -> f t  -- (->)
itraversed :: Applicativef  =>   Indexed i a b -> s -> f t
```

where

```
newtype Indexed i a b = Indexed { runIndexed :: i -> a -> b }
```

---

Why both are needed? `itraverse` is way more easy to implement. Usually
it's already there (e.g. `traverseWithKey` in `containers`).

---

The operations require concrete instantiations of the optics
(e.g. `set` requires `ASetter`). Shortly: it's easier for compiler to figure
out stuff, as we don't use `Rank2Types`.

`Indexed` i.e. separate `newtype` is needed so we can talk
about `a -> b` and `i -> a -> b` as instances of `Indexable`;
that let's us degrade indexed optics into regular ones:

```
Prelude Control.Lens> over itraversed (+1) [1,2,3]
[2,3,4]
```

and having `p a (f b) -> q s (f t)` (where `p` can be `(->)` or `Indexable`)
let us compose indexed and regular optics:

```
Prelude Control.Lens> over (itraversed . traversed)  (+1) [[1,2],[3]]
[[2,3],[4]]
```

or

```
Prelude Control.Lens> iover (itraversed . traversed) (,) [[1,2],[3]]
[[(0,1),(1,2)],[(0,3)]]
```

Comment: Okay, I think this makes sense.  So if we weren't using `Indexable` (and we didn't have `Index`), we wouldn't be able to compose regular optics with indexed optics, right?  For instance, we're not able to compose `itraverse` with `traverse` and get a regular non-indexed traversal, right?  Is there any time I would want to use `itraverse` instead of `itraversed` if I am working with the operations like `set`, `over`, etc?

Comment: @illabout i you use everything thru lens combinators, then you probably won't need `itraverse`. Though sometimes it reads better than `itraverseOf itraversed` (subjectively)

Comment: anecdotally, `traverse . itraverse` "works", but `traverse . traverse` doesn't, so it just better to not use those. It's the same as that you can do `(traverse . traverse) f xss` without any `lens` stuff (`traverseOf = id`).